# Chromium Popup/Context Menu artifacts intermitently won't go away

Tags: 64-bit, kubuntu, chromium

I'm running `Chromium 18.0.997.0 (Developer Build 116462 Linux) Ubuntu 11.10` and occasionally when I open a context menu it will leave an artifact on the screen that is always above any application and will not go away unless I completely close down Chromium. This problem happens intermittently and is hard to reproduce, but it happens at least once a day and may be related to how long I have it open since I only ever close when there is an update or this problem occurs. I've attached an example of what happens. Anyone have any ideas if and how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, but this seems to be a Chromium + Ubuntu related bug. This issue has been reported on the Chromium bug [tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108899) and I suggest you vote for it (click on the star) or add any information to help identify/solve the issue.